# Polynomials/Trinomial Word Problem

Tags: polynomials

I have no idea how to do this:

The product of two consecutive odd integers is $143$. Find their sum.

We're learning about factoring quadratics, trinomials, polynomials, etc. I haven't seen this though...

So I did $w(w+2) = 143$.
$w^2 + 2w = 143$.

Now what?

Comment: You haven't used that they are both odd numbers. Try $(2n-1)(2n+1)=143.$ It makes it simpler.

Comment: now you can solve the resulting quadratic equation $w^2+2w-143=0$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks User.

Comment: @coffeemath, where did you get the 2n-1 and +1 from?

Comment: johnny: One form of an odd number is $2n-1$ which for $n=1,2,3,...$ gives the odd positive numbers $1,3,5,...$ in that order. Then the next odd after $2n-1$ is $(2n-1)+2=2n+1.$

Comment: Now I have (w-11)(w+13). So w = 11 and w = -13? How do I find their sums? -2 isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the question you were asked: it doesn't have a unique answer. As you observe, you get $w = 11$ and $w = -13$; these correspond to two possible answers:
$$
(-13)(-11) = 143 \\
(11)(13) = 143
$$
In the first case, the sum is $-24$; in the second, the sum is $24$.

BTW, following @coffeemath's suggestion, you get 
$$(2n-1)(2n+1) = 143 \\
4n^2 - 1 = 143 \\
4n^2 = 144\\
n^2 = 36 \\
n = \pm 6
$$
so that your numbers ($2n+1$ and $2n-1$) are
$$
2 \cdot 6 + 1 = 13; 2\cdot 6 -1 = 11 
$$
in the first case, and 
$$
2 \cdot (-6) + 1 = -11; 2\cdot(-6) -1 = -13 
$$
in the second.